# How do you unit test HTML.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes

I would like to be able to unit test that an HTML.ActionLink or Url.Action will return the correct url based on my route. What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do, is to test your routes. The `ActionLink` method and its friends all use the routing engine to build the URLs, so if the routing is ok, the links will be ok.

Here is a short article on that topic:

- [Testing URL Generation on Routes in MVC Framework](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2009/08/27/testing-url-generation-on-routes-in-mvc-framework.aspx)

Comment: Link is an oldie but a goodie, in particular since Eilon owns MVC nowadays.

Comment: The link is dead, so the post is just partially helpful.